# Excel Copying Sheet Lose Chart and Data Table Format When Source File is Closed

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, formatting

I am copying a worksheet from one workbook to another which contains a combo chart (histogram on top, data table on the bottom). The numbers are formatted as percentage (i.e. like "90.20%") and thus the numbers are showed as percentage in the chart. However, as long as I closed the source file, the numbers in the chart are changing back to general (i.e. becoming "0.902000"); once the source file is opened, the numbers are changing back to percentage again. I am wondering if there is way to preserve the number formatting even when the source file is closed.

I am using Excel 2016. The source file is xlsb and I have tried saving my file in xlsx and xlsb format, neither works. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue, and I can also reproduce this situation in my tests.

I found some similar situations in google search, and it doesn't seem to be improved. .

I suggest you close the newly created file after copying, and then close the source file.

Comment: Thank you. I will just keep the source files opened as a work around. It's frustrated that this issue is known for a long time but never solved by Microsoft.

Comment: You can click the "smiley" icon in the upper right corner of excel to submit feedback.